# How to use variables from controller in ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am just learning AngularJS and want to use in ng-repeat variable from controller (without using scope), but it doesn't work. Could anyone point out my mistake? This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select>
    <option ng-repeat="x in myCtrl.names">{{x}}</option>
</select>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    var that = this;
    that.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi there, could you explain a bit about how it's not working? Are you getting an error, or is it just failing?

Comment: @ChrisAlexander It just doesn't work. You can try to run the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Set the variable on the scope.**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
});
```

Use variable in the controller

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function() {
    var self = this;
    self.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as myController">
    <select>
        <option ng-repeat="x in myController.names">{{x}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to use scope.

Comment: @iJava I've updated the answer to include a solution with no scope.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using direct controller name, use that name which we mention where the controller name declare in html code using 'as' keyword.

For example:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function() {
    var viewData = this;
    viewData.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
});

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as Ctrl">
    <select>
        <option ng-repeat="x in Ctrl.names">{{x}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```